# How to escape a % sign in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I do a full text search using LIKE clause and the text can contain a '%'.

What is a good way to search for a % sign in an sqlite database?

I did try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text_string LIKE '%[%]%'
```

but that doesn't work in sqlite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> If the optional ESCAPE clause is present, then the expression following the ESCAPE keyword must evaluate to a string consisting of a single character. This character may be used in the LIKE pattern to include literal percent or underscore characters. The escape character followed by a percent symbol (%), underscore (_), or a second instance of the escape character itself matches a literal percent symbol, underscore, or a single escape character, respectively.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE text_string LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\';

That worked!

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve same thing with the below query

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE instr(text_string, ?)>0`

**Here :**

`?  => your search word`

**Example :**

You can give text directly like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE instr(text_string, '%')>0`

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE instr(text_string, '98.9%')>0` etc.

Hope this helps better.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE parent_path = ? OR parent_path LIKE ? ESCAPE '\'
```

ESCAPE clause must be included if value to use for like parameter contains % or _

Then for query parameter, replace all % with \% and _ with \_ in parameter value for like